# Add appointment to emacs diary from org-mode agenda

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I would like to add appointments with a timestamp including the time of the day to my emacs diary.org file from agenda view using "i d" on a date (as far as I know this invokes  `org-agenda-diary-entry`). Typing for example `12:00 Lunch` at the prompt produces the following entry in diary.org:

```
*** 2012-11-16 Friday 
**** 12:00 Lunch
 <2012-11-16 Fr>
```

This appointment is displayed properly in my agenda view:

```
  diary:      12:00...... Lunch
```

However, I would like to have the time of the day within the timestamp like:

```
    **** Lunch
 <2012-11-16 Fr 12:00>
```

How can I achieve this kind of behaviour which I need for syncing my appointments with org-caldav-sync?